# $\nabla \varphi . \text{d}\mathbf{x} = \text{d}\varphi$ or $\nabla \varphi . \text{d}\mathbf{x} = 3\text{ d}\varphi$?

Tags: calculus

This might be a daft question, but I am confused by the vector identity $\nabla \varphi . \text{d}\mathbf{x} = \text{d}\varphi$, where $\varphi(\mathbf{x})$ is a scalar function, that is used in my lecture notes.

As far as I understand, $\nabla \varphi = (\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x},\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial y},\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial z})$ and $\text{d}\mathbf{x} = (\text{d}x, \text{d}y, \text{d}z)$, so their dot product should give $3 \text{ d}\varphi$. Am I wrong?

Apologies if this is a duplicate question, but it's quite hard to search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to read here, for example; "differential in several variables":
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function

$d\varphi$ is called TOTAL DIFFERENTIAL.